# Flash Player Settings Panel not showing Privacy or Local Storage tabs on Safari for Mac

Tags: actionscript-3, safari, flash, flashdevelop

I'm making a small flash application for a website. It works perfectly apart from one small thing, I have implemented a way to bring up the flash settings menu to a user specified tab.

This works as expected in all cases apart from in Safari on Mac, the Local Storage and Privacy tabs are missing. This is a bit of a problem as the Privacy tab is the most important one in this system.

This only happens when the swf is hosted on a subdomain (for example the swf is hosted on bs5.somewebsite.com and then embedded on somewebsite.com) and I'd write it off as an Apple security quirk however to make matters a bit more frustrating some SWF files from other sources (which I do not have the source code for, JWPlayer for example) can access all tabs in the settings window even on Safari for Mac and even when hosted on the subdomain.

I'm authoring this in FlashDevelop.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you are trying to view your SWF through an iFrame. Safari has a "feature" which disables some functionality for sites loaded in iFrames to try and prevent 3rd parties from tracking you.

A simple test is to directly view the page in the iFrame and see if the Local Storage and Privacy tabs appear.

Comment: This happens when viewing in an iframe or directly on the page, only on safari though.