# Adobe security setting popup not showing remember option

Tags: security

[Adobe security setting popups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhehI.png)

I am using flash player for audio recording purpose. I want 1st popup but may program showing 2nd popup. How get I get first popup

### My Action Script Code is given below.

package
{
    import fr.kikko.lab.ShineMP3Encoder;

```
import flash.events.ErrorEvent;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.events.StatusEvent;

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.media.Microphone;
import flash.system.Security;

import org.bytearray.micrecorder.*;
import org.bytearray.micrecorder.events.RecordingEvent;
import org.bytearray.micrecorder.encoder.WaveEncoder;

import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.ActivityEvent;

import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import flash.media.Sound;

import org.as3wavsound.WavSound;
import org.as3wavsound.WavSoundChannel;

public class Main extends Sprite
{
    // private var recBar:RecBar = new RecBar();

    private var mic:Microphone;
    private var waveEncoder:WaveEncoder = new WaveEncoder();
    private var recorder:MicRecorder = new MicRecorder(waveEncoder);

    private var maxTime:Number = 30;    // default time to record in seconds

    private var tts:WavSound;
    private var playingChannel:WavSoundChannel;

    private var mp3Encoder:ShineMP3Encoder;
    private var mp3done:Boolean = false;    // if we done converting to mp3

    private var wasRecorded:Boolean = false;    // if we done recording

    private var isPreviewing:Boolean = false;   // if we are in previewing state now?
    private var isConverting:Boolean = false;   // if we are in converting state now?

    public function Main():void
    {
        mic = Microphone.getMicrophone();
        mic.setSilenceLevel(mic.activityLevel);
        mic.gain = 50;
        mic.setLoopBack(false);
        mic.setUseEchoSuppression(true);

        recorder.addEventListener(RecordingEvent.RECORDING, recording);

        addCommands();
    }

    public function jStartRecording(max_time:Number):void
    {
        if (mic != null) {
            mp3done = false;
            wasRecorded = false;
            maxTime = max_time;

            recorder.record();
            // recorder.microphone.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, onMicStatus);

            ExternalInterface.call("justrec.recordingStarted");
        }
        else
        {
            ExternalInterface.call("justrec.recordingError");
        }
    }

    public function jStopRecording():void
    {
        recorder.stop();
        wasRecorded = true;

        mic.setLoopBack(false);
        ExternalInterface.call("justrec.recordingStopped");
    }

    public function jPreview():void
    {
        if(wasRecorded) {
            previewRecording();
        }
    }
    public function jStopPreview():void
    {
        if(isPreviewing) {
            stopPreviewRecording();
        }
    }

    // convert WAV to MP3
    public function jConvert2MP3():void
    {
        if(wasRecorded) {
            convert2mp3();
        }
    }

    public function jSendFileToServer():void
    {
        // do nothing if we have not converted our record
        if(mp3done) {
            sendRecording();            
        }
        else {
            ExternalInterface.call("justrec.mp3ConvertingError");
        }
    }

    /* ************ */
    /* Private area */
    /* ************ */

    private function recording(e:RecordingEvent):void
    {
        var currentTime:int = Math.floor(e.time / 1000);
        ExternalInterface.call("justrec.recordingActivity",  String(currentTime),  mic.activityLevel);

        if(currentTime >= maxTime )
        {
            // force stop recording
            jStopRecording();
        }
    }

    private function previewRecording():void
    {
        if(isConverting) {
            return;
        }

        if(isPreviewing) {
            stopPreviewRecording();
        }

        isPreviewing = true;    // force into previewing mode

        tts = new WavSound(recorder.output);
  playingChannel = tts.play();

        // ?? ExternalInterface.call("justrec.previewStarted");
    }
    private function stopPreviewRecording():void
    {
  playingChannel.stop();
        isPreviewing = false;

        // ?? ExternalInterface.call("justrec.previewStopped");
    }

    // convert to mp3 using ShineMP3Encoder
    private function convert2mp3():void {
        if(isConverting) {
            return;
        }

        if(isPreviewing) {
            stopPreviewRecording();
        }

        // set position of ByteArray with WAV data to 0
        // either converting sticks if previewing is done
        recorder.output.position = 0;
        isConverting = true;

        mp3Encoder = new ShineMP3Encoder(recorder.output);
        mp3Encoder.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, mp3EncodeComplete);
        mp3Encoder.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, mp3EncodeProgress);
        mp3Encoder.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, mp3EncodeError);
        mp3Encoder.start();
    }

    private function mp3EncodeProgress(event: ProgressEvent) : void {
        var percent:int = Math.round(event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal * 100);
        ExternalInterface.call("justrec.mp3Converting", String(percent));
    }

    private function mp3EncodeError(event: ErrorEvent) : void {
        isConverting = false;
        ExternalInterface.call("justrec.mp3ConvertingError");
    }

    private function mp3EncodeComplete(event: Event) : void {
        mp3done = true; // converting flag
        isConverting = false;
        ExternalInterface.call("justrec.mp3Converted");
    }

    // send data to server
    private function sendRecording():void
    {
        var _var1:String = '';
        var globalParam:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;

        for (var element:String in globalParam) {
        if (element == 'host'){
        _var1 = globalParam[element];
            }
        }

        if(_var1 != '') {
            var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(_var1);
    req.contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
            req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            // req.data = recorder.output; -- for WAV data
            req.data = mp3Encoder.mp3Data;  // for MP3 data

            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(req);
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, sendComplete);
            loader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, sendProgress);
        }
    }

    private function sendProgress(event: ProgressEvent) : void {
        var percent:int = Math.round(event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal * 100);
        ExternalInterface.call("justrec.sendingProgress", String(percent));
    }

    // done sending record
    private function sendComplete(event: Event) : void {
        ExternalInterface.call("justrec.sendingFinished");
    }

    /* ***************** */
    // helper functions //
    /* *************** */

    private function addCommands():void
    {

        ExternalInterface.addCallback("jStartRecording", jStartRecording);
        ExternalInterface.addCallback("jStopRecording", jStopRecording);

        ExternalInterface.addCallback("jPreview", jPreview);
        ExternalInterface.addCallback("jStopPreview", jStopPreview);

        ExternalInterface.addCallback("jConvert2MP3", jConvert2MP3);
        ExternalInterface.addCallback("jSendFileToServer", jSendFileToServer);
    }

    // dispatches on allowing/denying access to Camera/Microphone
/*
    private function onMicStatus(event:StatusEvent):void 
    { 
        ExternalInterface.call("justrec.micStatus");

        if (event.code == "Microphone.Muted")
        {
            ExternalInterface.call("justrec.recordingError");
            // trace("Microphone access was denied.");
        }
    }
*/

}   // class Main
} // package
```

Comment: What OS and browser are you using?
Is it reproducible in  different environments?
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631020/flash-player-settings-panel-not-showing-privacy-or-local-storage-tabs-on-safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631020/flash-player-settings-panel-not-showing-privacy-or-local-storage-tabs-on-safari)

Comment: I am using Windows 7 and chrome browse. It showing only allow deny popup. but I want remember option also.